# How can I insert images in Yii2 kartik-v/yii2-mpdf?

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I can’t insert images when I create a pdf file with Kartik. It's possible to insert an image in kartik-v/yii2-mpdf?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it depends how do you render the content. I prefer to render it via `renderPartial` (render the view) so you have all the HTML options (with limited styling).
E.g. a code from my project

```
    use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

    public function actionContract(){
            $model = $this->getModel();
            $content = $this->renderPartial('@admin/views/contract/pdf/contract', ['contract' => $model]);
    
            $odd = [
                'L' => ['content' => $this->renderPartial('@admin/views/contract/pdf/contract-header-left')],
                'C' => ['content' => $this->renderPartial('@admin/views/contract/pdf/contract-header-center', ['contract' => $model])],
                'R' => ['content' => $this->renderPartial('@admin/views/contract/pdf/contract-header-right')]
            ];
    
            $footer = [
                'C' => ['content' => $this->renderPartial('@admin/views/contract/pdf/contract-footer')],
            ];
    
            $pdf = new Pdf([
                'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
                'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
                'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
                'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
                'content' => $content,
    
                'cssFile' => '@admin/web/source_assets/contract/scss/pdf.scss',
                'methods' => [
                    'SetHeader' => [
                        ['odd' => $odd],
                        ['even' => $odd],
                    ],
                    'SetFooter' => [
                        ['odd' => $footer],
                        ['even' => $footer],
                    ],
                ],
                'marginTop' => 24,
                'marginBottom' => 28,
                'marginLeft' => 12,
                'marginRight' => 12,
            ]);
    
            return $pdf->render();
    }
```

and then, in the view you can do something like this
`<img style="width: 2mm; height: 2mm;" src="/admin/web/source_assets/contract/img/x.png" alt="">`

Comment: The solution is set $this->_mpdf->showImageErrors = true; in file ... /vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/Pdf.php in method setApi().